# Access HTTP Headers while loading the AngularJS Application

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

I am working on a new application which is using AngualarJS framework. For User Authentication, I am using a cleartrust authentication for validating user credentials. Once the application Url is accessed it navigates to clear trust login page and when clicks on login button it will validate the user and once it’s a valid user it navigates to start up page say “index.html” Also clear trust passes HTTP Headers which contains user information’s like UserId, email, working location, etc. So question is, when app.js file is loaded how can I access HTTP Header from my app.js file? Basically I require to get http header while loading the application. Could anyone help me how to access HTTP Headers?

Example for this scenario is, Say we are using facebook login for my application to authenticate user. So while accessing the url (mysite.com/index.html) it should navigate to facebook login and allow the user to login with his/her credentials. Once this is validated it will be redirected to index.html (which is the startup page for my app in mysite.com). Here in app.js I need to access User Name, User Display Name, country, etc (say user information details) from the header.

Comment: Could you please put some code here so someone can help?

Comment: Hi, how do you do the authentication against Cleartrust from your angular code? I am interested in that as I am searching for a way to do that.